# How to use @Singleton of Guice ?

Tags: android, guice

I need to make one instance of some class - and this one instance need to be accessible from any place in the code.

So, I found the Guice... and i want to use the '@Singleton' from this package but i don't find any example or some doc to how to use it and how to make the declaration.

Comment: You should check roboguice.org

Comment: i checked ... still this is not understandable

Comment: Is this Android-related?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is in Android anything specific about singletons... Singleton is a singleton you do public static INSTANCE = new MyClass() within MyClass. And yes, the Android Application class exists throughout the entire life of the program. Must be I'm misunderstanding the question

Comment: i know how to impliment singleton :) ... but i wanted to know if there is some easyer way to impl.

Comment: Ah I see you wanted something in Android that could be treated as a singleton. I see now, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, **My answer is not a specific for @Singleton of Guice**, But If you want to Make a class which is accessible through all your activities then I think,You have to use **Application** class of Android. (This is my personal opinion for your need)

The way to do this is to create your own subclass of `android.app.Application`, and then specify that **class in the application tag in your manifest**. Now Android will automatically create an instance of that class and make it available for your entire application. You can access it from any context using the `Context.getApplicationContext()` method (Activity also provides a method `getApplication()` which has the exact same effect):

```
class MyApp extends Application {

  private String myState;

  public String getState(){
    return myState;
  }
  public void setState(String s){
    myState = s;
  }
}

class Blah extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    ...
    MyApp appState = ((MyApp)getApplicationContext());
    String state = appState.getState();
    ...
  }
}
```

This has essentially the same effect as using a static variable or singleton, but integrates quite well into the existing Android framework. Note that this will not work across processes (should your app be one of the rare ones that has multiple processes).

Here is the nice tutorial about how to use it, [Extending the Android Application class and dealing with Singleton](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)

Comment: Even easier is to use Scala language instead. You can just define an `object` and you're done: it can be accessed from any Activity and other classes. This is actually like implementing singleton factory, but scala does all this automatically for you.

Answer (score 7):

@Singleton is very easy to use. It just goes like this

```
@Singleton
public class A {

    @Inject
    public A() {
    }
}
```

Please note however that the singleton is one per injector and not per VM. Singleton is a scope type and GUICE also allows custom scopes which can be very useful. Please see links below.

When you use this in another class you just need to inject it.

```
public class B {
   @Inject
   public B(A a) {
   }
}
```

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Scopes

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: So, in public B(A a) ... it will take always the same instance that was created in puclic C(A a) ?

Comment: Yes as long as your injector is same. Its basically a scoped instance.  So in that object hierarchy instance "a" will be the same under that injector.

Comment: Be aware, with Guice there are a lot of ways to do the same thing.  One could also specify singleton-ness in a module during binding in configure() with bind(Iface.class).to(Impl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON) , but I've found that Guice 3.0 cannot always guarantee uniqueness using the binding annotation in Module.configure().  @SidMalni 's solution seems to get around problems with Module.configure() binding approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DestinationViewManger {

    private static final DestinationViewManger instance = new DestinationViewManger();
    public Boolean flag=false;

 // Private constructor prevents instantiation from other classes
    private DestinationViewManger(){   }

    public static DestinationViewManger getInstance() {
        return instance;
    } 
}
```

//try this singleton class once. no need for getter and setter method

```
DestinationViewManger dstv;

dstv=DestinationViewManger.getInstance();

dstv.flag=true; //set the value for your flag

boolean whatFlagboo=dstv.flag; //get your flag wherever you want
```